# Solving a differential equation for a factorial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I started off with the equation:
$$
f(x)=f'(x)[\frac{1}{g(x)}-1] + f(x)[\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}]
$$
i then simplified into:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{1-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}}{\frac{1}{g(x)}-1} = \frac{g'(x)-g(x)}{g(x)-1}
$$
integrated both sides to get:
$$
ln(f(x)) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{g'(n)-g(n)}{g(n)-1} dn
$$

$$
f(x) = \exp[\int_{1}^{x}\frac{g'(n)-g(n)}{g(n)-1}dn]
$$

So now i know my value for $f(x) = \Gamma[x+1]$, is there any way for me to find a solution for g(x)? Also as a note i didn't want to make $f(x) = \Gamma[x+1]$ initially because i wanted to avoid taking derivatives of the gamma function.

Comment: With $x!$ I suppose you mean the generalisation of the factorial namely the $\Gamma$-[function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)?

Comment: @Winther yes i should have made that clear in the question, sorry

Comment: If you really want to avoid derivatives of $\Gamma$ then you can use the equation $\Gamma(x+1) = x\Gamma(x)$ to derive an equation for $g$: $\int_x^{x+1}\frac{g'-g}{g-1}dn = \log x$. However, by now taking the derivative will relate $g(x),g'(x)$ to $g(x+1),g'(x+1)$ so I would not reccomend it.